# Firebase cloud functions FCM notification not working after changing android project directory

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I moved the project directory and tried running the project but received an error message saying "installation fail with invalid file." so I moved the project file back.

Running the project still didn't work so I cleaned and rebuilt the project. After I did that, the app is working just fine with firebase storage and database functioning well except for firebase cloud functions where I no longer receive push notification.

If anyone has just a slight idea of what I need to do now please let me know! Thanks in advance!

(Edit)
Here is the error message in Firebase Functions Logs:

```
Error: Messaging payload contains an invalid value for the "notification.title" property. Values must be strings.
at FirebaseMessagingError.Error (native)
at FirebaseMessagingError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:25:28)
at new FirebaseMessagingError (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:130:23)
at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging.js:486:27
at Array.forEach (native)
at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging.js:483:32
at Array.forEach (native)
at Messaging.validateMessagingPayload (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging.js:476:21)
at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging.js:313:37
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

MyFirebaseMessagingService.java

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "FirebaseMessagingService";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        String notificationTitle = null, notificationBody = null;

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            notificationTitle = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
            notificationBody = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
        }

        // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
        // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
        sendNotification(notificationTitle, notificationBody);
    }


    private void sendNotification(String notificationTitle, String notificationBody) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setAutoCancel(true)   //Automatically delete the notification
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher) //Notification icon
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
            .setContentText(notificationBody)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri);


        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

index.js

```
//import firebase functions modules
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
//import admin module
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);


// Listens for new messages added to messages/:pushId
exports.pushNotification = functions.database.ref('/Report/{pushId}').onWrite( event => {

    console.log('Push notification event triggered');

    //  Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
    var valueObject = event.data.val();

    if(valueObject.photoUrl != null) {
      valueObject.photoUrl= "Sent you a photo!";
    }

  // Create a notification
    const payload = {
        notification: {
            title:valueObject.name,
            body: valueObject.desc || valueObject.photoUrl,
            sound: "default"
        }
    };

  //Create an options object that contains the time to live for the notification and the priority
    const options = {
        priority: "high",
        timeToLive: 60 * 60 * 24
    };


    return admin.messaging().sendToTopic("pushNotifications", payload, options);
});
```

inside AndroidManifest.xml application tag

```
<service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

.json

```
{
  "Report" : {
    "-Kpne6Xp29_MkkB_-aPA" : {
      "date" : "Jul 24, 4:14 PM",
      "desc" : "bubble gum",
      "image" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/report-f7656.appspot.com/o/Material%2Fcropped620487630.jpg?alt=media&token=e63a7fd8-b7ed-4277-9709-f5182f2db71d",
      "name" : "kenzo",
      "title" : "ditto",
      "type" : "Material",
      "uid" : "7DxLHiNhUUYwPTKnRx0ylJ2O8zb2"
    },
    "-Kpnj6Dm0uO_YR3qrB0V" : {
      "date" : "Jul 24, 4:36 PM",
      "desc" : "insta story",
      "image" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/report-f7656.appspot.com/o/Material%2Fcropped2010735531.jpg?alt=media&token=940fedda-4333-4146-9a3f-a891a5ca412c",
      "name" : "kenzo",
      "title" : "ddlovato",
      "type" : "Material",
      "uid" : "7DxLHiNhUUYwPTKnRx0ylJ2O8zb2"
    }
  },
  "Users" : {
    "7DxLHiNhUUYwPTKnRx0ylJ2O8zb2" : {
      "name" : "kenzo"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Where you able to receive the notification earlier?. Also check whether your server side is giving any error

Comment: @TerrilThomas yes, I was able to receive notification earlier.

Comment: Check whether your service is triggered and the regId is saved at your  database and one thing is to be also checked whether your app is open when you receive notification you can also try using Cloudmessaging portal to send custom message for trial purpose

Comment: @TerrilThomas how do I check for regId? There are logs in the functions and sending custom message works too even when my app is open. There are some errors shown in the logs which were present when the notification system was working previously.

Comment: @TerrilThomas so sorry, it didn't have the error message previously. the error messages are found at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/  and /user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/

Comment: Can you share you snippet related to FCM

Comment: @TerrilThomas here they are.

Comment: Do you have a class which extends firebaseinstanceidservice

Comment: @TerrilThomas no i don't...

Comment: you need to that create regId which is saved in your database and then passed to FCM

Comment: Now I am wondering how were you able to receive notifications earlier

Comment: @TerrilThomas I am not very clear about the regId. is there any link that might help? I wonder how it worked before... I unknowingly messed it up I guess

Comment: @TerrilThomas if you are talking about the generated random pushId then yes I do have them in each child node.

Comment: @TerrilThomas I added the json file (see above).

Comment: @TerrilThomas I somehow managed to get FCM working with the same code and persisting error... it's working now and I don't know how...

Comment: Exactly the same thing happened to me today.. and its working again by itself.